# How can I make key points in Latex and arrange them in a certain way?

Tags: color, itemize, msword, structure

I have written the following text in Microsoft Word and would like to write it in the same way in Latex (with the same design criteria):

[image: text from wort]

I tried to get the same structure by using `itemize`. But that didn't work the way I wanted.
Could some explain me how I can reach the same structure with Latex? Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Could you post your example using itemize?  That would give us something to start with.  Could you clarify "didn't work the way I wanted"?  The only I can think of is you want "enumerate" instead of itemize.  But it's not clear how closely you want to match the output from Word.

Comment: In order to customize an `enumerate` environment, which I suggest using for a nested, numbered list, you may want to take a look at the `enumitem` package.

Comment: It should look the same in Latex as it does in Word (see picture). The same structur and all should be the same. 
It is not possible with itemize. I have already deleted it.

Comment: For numberd lists, as the one in your picture seems to be, use `enumerate` instead of `itemize`.

Comment: Since you mention wanting to replicate the screenshot using LaTex: exactly as it is: Is it intentional, that the vertical space between teh bold text in a) and the following line is larger than the space between the bold text in b) and the following line starting with "Left"?

Comment: To be honest, that's not so important for now. Actually, the distance should be the same for both. In spite of everything, I still don't know how I can do it in latex so that it looks like in word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following nested `enumerate` lists, which were customized using the `enumitem` package might serve as a point to start from:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*)]
  \item text
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*), font=\bfseries, before=\bfseries]
    \item Dependent two-sided...
 
    \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\normalfont}l}
      Left: text and some numbers here \\
      Right: text and some numbers here
    \end{tabular}
    \item Wilcoxon Text
   
    \begin{tabular}{@{}>{\normalfont}l}
      Left: text and some numbers here \\
      Right: text and some numbers here
    \end{tabular}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```